# Bidirectional One-To-Many association with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables
`A (id)` and `B (a_id, b_id)`

Where A-B is a bidirectional One-To-Many association,
and `B` has a composite primary key `(a_id, b_id)` where `a_id` is a foreign key referring to A's `id`.

My current attempt is as following (using `@IdClass`):

```java
@Entity(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a",
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();


... constructors/getters/setters
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "B")
public class B {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    @MapsId("a_id")
    private A a;

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    private int bId;

    @Data
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private int aId;
        private int bId;
    }

... constructors/getters/setters
}
```

Then it throws an exception: `Property of @IdClass not found in entity B: aId`

What is the correct way to model such bidirectional One-To-Many association with composite key using JPA (spring-data-jpa/hibernate)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Hibernate ORM documentation [for a detailed explanation of this type of mapping with `@IdClass`](http://The%20Hibernate%20ORM%20documentation%20explaing):

```
@Entity(name = "B")
@IdClass(BPK.class)
public class B {

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @Column(name = "b_id")
    private int bId;

... constructors/getters/setters
}

public class BPK implements Serializable {
    private A a;

    private int bId;

... constructors/getters/setters
}
```

`@MapsId` [has another purpose](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived): it's for when a *-to-one association has the same id as the entity associated.